# submitting a form that is within a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I tried

```
var form = $('.form').clone();
form.submit();
```

so I'm trying to submit a form inside variable form which is not exactly rendered on the page since it was cloned from another form...but I'm not seeing any signs that the form has been submitted

my question is...is this use case even possible in the first place? Can you use jquery to submit a form that is contained within a javascript variable and is not actually rendered on the page?

If not, is it possible to tweak it somehow so that you can indeed submit a form inside a variable? (without actually rerendering it on the page of course)

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/mjYAm/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I have done it in the past:

```
var form;

form = document.createElement("form");
$(form)
.attr("method", "post")
.attr("style", "display: none")
.attr("action", "your_url");

document.body.appendChild(form);

form.submit();
$(form).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that a form which is not part of the active DOM (i.e. not "rendered" as part of the page) cannot be submitted.

You could probably workaround by adding the form to the page as an invisible element (e.g. as a child of a div with style `display:none`).  Alternatively, you could build an [AJAX request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) out of the form contents.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the cloned `form` element to body of the document before you submit it.

But why do you need to clone and submit? Anyways the page will refresh even if you append it to body and submit.

Why don't you use `ajax` to submit the form?

Comment: There is an upload file field in the form so using ajax is difficult